# Will npm try to avoid installing a deprecated package version?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning

I could not find any documentation which says that npm will not try to install a deprecated package version.

example:

```
2.0.0-beta.2  2.0.0-beta.5  2.0.0-rc.9
```

So if I install ^2.0.0-beta.2, it will resolve to 2.0.0-rc.9

And if I deprecate 2.0.0-rc.9

```
2.0.0-beta.2  2.0.0-beta.5  2.0.0-rc.9
                           (deprecated)
```

Now if I install ^2.0.0-beta.2, it will resolve to 2.0.0-beta.5

But I could not find any documentation which proves this behavior. Can someone please help to validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and confirmed that it does indeed ignore deprecated versions if there is another version it can use. (I temporarily deprecated `metal-name` version 1.3.1 and then ran `npm install metal-name@1`. It installed version 1.3.0 instead of 1.3.1. When I removed the deprecation for version 1.3.1, it went back to installing 1.3.1 when I ran `npm install metal-name@1`.

I can not find this behavior mentioned in the npm CLI documentation. However, I can find it [mentioned in the commit log for the npm CLI client](https://github.com/npm/cli/commit/78bebc0cedc4ce75c974c47b61791e6ca1ccfd7e).

npm uses [`npm-pick-manifest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-pick-manifest) to determine what to install. The README for that module says:

> Prefers non-deprecated versions to deprecated versions.

Comment: But includeDeprecated flag is not present in the latest branch though.

Comment: but note that evidence isn't the same as knowing - unless there are docs that explicitly state this behaviour, that behaviour could suddenly be different tomorrow.

Comment: @Abhijeet There's no need for it to be in the latest branch because that behavior of npm-pick-manifest is now the default behavior. (I've added this information to my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

NPM will do whatever you told it to do, based on your package.json rule for each dependency. If you use `^` as version prefix then yeah: you literally told NPM to use "whatever is the most up to date minor release".

See both [the documentation for dependency management](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies) and [the semver range documentation](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions) for what syntax is accepted and what they all mean.

Comment: My question is, will npm ignore a deprecated version even though it's the closest match to the semver?

Comment: That's definitely a question to search the docs for, and if you can't find it, do what open source relies on: file an issue with the npm folks to get that information added into the documentation in the place you were looking but couldn't find it. So that _everyone_ can find that information in the first place they will be looking for answers, rather than the last place.