# “This package has been deprecated” refers to specific version or all?

Tags: npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/node-http-handler?activeTab=versions

When I look at the latest version here I can see that it warns about the package being deprecated.

But other versions of that library on the website do not give this message on their webpage. For example, click the second latest version.. the warning is no longer highlighted.

Now, for this specific example I KNOW that it is advising not to use the aws-sdk prefix version and use smithy going forward, ie there will likely never be another release for this library again.. so it’s not a great example but what I mean is:

Not relating to this example, could a deprecation refer to just one specific version of a library? Perhaps due to a security flaw that got introduced in this version. And by that logic, a downgrade (if there were no newer versions) could potentially be a non deprecated option?

Or, does deprecation refer to an entire package and all of its versions?

And also, is npm install smart enough to discern the difference? Say your dependency was carated.. would npm downgrade the package for you to go for the last non-deprecated version within that same major?

Hopefully this made a little bit of sense. I’m new to all of this

Comment: Amazon guys actually haven't done it right. When you deprecate a package, if you don't specify version, it deprecates everything (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/request?activeTab=versions for example, you won't see any non-deprecated version there). For most of the cases, I would suggest just keep your dependencies updated and if their latest version is giving deprecation notices during install, then yeah most likely they never will be updated and you should migrate according to the message.

Comment: A more general rule would be to never downgrade to fix deprecation warnings. Many packages only deprecate specific versions because they have fixed some regression or critical bug or security risk with newer version and people should upgrade from those. Again, if the latest version is deprecated, better to move away from that package. If some library maintainer is deprecating the latest version and are going to publish things in future, then it's their job to do a version-only bump so that the latest tag doesn't point to a deprecated version.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that there could be a moment in time where a security flaw is introduced in only the latest version, and for that reason that specific version becomes deprecated? And the solution could be to downgrade and await a newer version? Rather than immediately move away

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691726/will-npm-try-to-avoid-installing-a-deprecated-package-version

Seems that npm will downgrade if necessary

Comment: That may vary from case to case. You should refer to what the deprecation message for a particular package/version is saying. I, personally, haven't seen any such case where only the latest version is deprecated because of some security issue. Usually a whole range of versions is deprecated and CVEs are published. npm install should pick up CVEs associated with particular package versions even if the package is not deprecated.

Comment: I appreciate your answers so far. Two more questions if you don’t mind: 1) I’ve since looked up the expected behaviour here: https://docs.npmjs.com/deprecating-and-undeprecating-packages-or-package-versions and this would tell me that they’ve correctly identified that the entire package is deprecated rather than just that version. When you say they’ve not done it right what do you mean? How was I able to see other versions, but wasn’t able to see other versions for “request” like you linked me? Is that what you mean by them doing it wrong? What gives?

Comment: 2) Also, the link I posted to a previous SO question (about npm downgrading if the latest is deprecated) I’ve seen virtually no other evidence online about this behaviour, do you know if this is a thing? Sorry I am asking a lot I know its frustrating to read trust me

Comment: Regarding 1) aws folks probably run something like `npm deprecate @aws-sdk/node-http-handler@3.374.0 "this package is moved to smithy"` (or maybe @latest) instead of just running `npm deprecate @aws-sdk/node-http-handler "this package is moved to smithy"`

Comment: 2) Yes that's the expected behavior I guess, but it's quite rare. You can create an issue at https://github.com/npm/npm-pick-manifest asking them what's the reasoning behind that. But one thing that I'd recommend is keep your package.json updated. If you've specified `^1.2.3` then it won't install `1.2.2` even if `1.2.3` is deprecated and `1.2.2` is not. Use something like `npm-check-updates` (with `--target semver` or `greatest`) to keep those updated. For security issues maybe snyk or something like dependabot/renovate if you're using github.